# ruby - run http://localhost:3000/admin/users but redirect_to http://localhost:3000/admin/login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in Ruby on Rails. 
I want to run http://localhost:3000/admin/users to see users index page.
But when I run this link, it guide me to http://localhost:3000/admin/login.

Is there something wrongs with my route setting?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/new'
  get 'users/show'

  if Rails.env.development?
    mount LetterOpenerWeb::Engine, at: '/letter_opener'
  end
  root to: 'helps#top'

  # admin login
  get 'admin/login', to: 'admin/login#index', as: 'admin/login'
  get 'admin/logout', to: 'admin/login#logout'
  post 'admin/login/login'
  get 'admin', to: 'admin/projects#index', as: 'admin_top'


  namespace :admin do
    resources :users,  only: %i(index new create)
    resources :projects do
      resources :project_users
      resources :project_comments
    end
    resources :images
    resources :categories
    resources :campanies
  end
end
```

### users_controller.rb

```
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @users = User.all
end

def show
end

def new
    @user = User.new
end

def edit    
end

#Post /admin/projects
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
        flash[:notice] = 'User saved successfully'
        redirect_to :back
    else
        flash[:alert] = @user.errors
        binding.pry
        render :new
    end
end

def update
end

def destroy
end

private

    def set_user
        @user = User.find(params [:id])
    end

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:campany_id, :name, :email, :password_digest, :profile, :prefecture_id, :address)
    end
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UsersControllers` is under the admin namespace, that's to say you must be logged in order to access to this.

If you want to have access without validating the user is currently logged in, then you'll have to remove the constraint or verification to the controller or to make a new controller and index method which point to `/admin/users` but this time without the user verification.

That's:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
  ...
end

# config/routes.rb
get '/users', to: 'users#index'
```

`'/users'` or `'/admin/users'` as you want to do it, but if you use the last one then any person must infer that's a restricted resource .

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!